# Group Theory - Cyclic Groups & Direct Product

Tags: proof-writing, cyclic-groups, direct-product

Prove that if $G$ is an infinite group and $H$ is a group then $G \times H$ is cyclic if and only if $G$ is cyclic a $H =$ {${e_H}$}.

Solution: I can see that this is true but I don't know how to start my proof.

Comment: $G\times H$ is cyclic and infinite, and is thus isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is there any method to write this proof without mentioning isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G\times H$ is cyclic, let $\langle(g,h)\rangle=G\times H$, so $G=\langle g\rangle$ and $H=\langle h\rangle$ are cyclic as well. Let $H=\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some positive integer $n$. Then, if $h^2\neq h$, $(g^2,h)\not\in\langle(g,h)\rangle$; otherwise, $G$ is finite. Therefore, $h^2=h$, or $h=e_H$.

Comment: Didn't you mean $(g,h^2) \notin \langle(g,h)\rangle$ ? Also, I was wondering whether you'll be able to help me with the proof of the converse. I can not figure out how to prove that G is infinite given that G is cyclic and H is identity.

Comment: I mean $(g^2,h)$. In this case, the statement "if $G$ is infinite" is an assumption. So, you don't need to show it :) But the converse which you have to show is something different from that.